# Spark sql query causes partition count inflation

Tags: apache-spark-sql

The partition count in Spark (1.5.2) blows up on certain sql queries.

Can that be avoided?

In my case I have three tables (texts, owners, persons) on which I perform the following query:

```
sqlContext.sql(
                "SELECT t.* FROM texts t JOIN ("+
                        "SELECT o.TextId FROM "+
                        "owners o JOIN ("+
                        "SELECT UserId FROM person WHERE LOWER(name) "+
                        "RLIKE '.*"+escapeRegex(filter.name)+"\\s*$'"+
                        ") p ON (o.UserId=p.UserId) GROUP BY o.TextId"+
                        ") o "+
                        "ON (t.TextId = o.TextId)")
```

The partition count before the query is 2, afterwards it's 200 obtained using `textsDF.javaRDD().partitions().size()`

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Did you get what you are looking for.?

Comment: Jonathan, it is by default 200. Check this link  http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html  and search for the property.

Comment: To avoid the default value, you should set the property your self in your code as i suggested to lower value (to 2 or 4). Then you will get lesser partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of partitions for Join/Group by or any operation that has shuffle, depends on the property "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions". This must have been set to 200 in your cluster configuration.

**The importance of this property:** This decides the number of reducer(kind of, to understand) operations on the data. By setting this property higher, you can ensure there is good amount of parallelism is there.

Any how, you can change that property as per your needs. You can set as below to SparkConf, with any number.

```
conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","2");
```

Note: setting it to lower will degrade the performance, which increases the amount of network usage and lesser parallelism.

On another note, the parallelism on file reading depends on the default parallelism property which tells number of tasks per core/ number of blocks in your hdfs data. But for any operation that has shuffle, it is dependent on the property that i have mentioned.

Comment: `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` isn't set by my code nor is it set in the environment. I use `.setMaster("local[4]")` to initialize my configuration. Despite this, `sqlContext.read().json(...)` creates only 2 partitions. 
That's why I use `.repartition(4)` on my `DataFrame`. The first query leaves the partition count untouched. The second query right afterwards changes the count to 200. In the current project, using many partitions results in a terrible performance (even if I was running non-locally) because every partition has a large initialization overhead (in `.mapPartitions()`).

Comment: Jonathan, it is by default 200. Check this link  http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html  and search for the property.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks! Still I'm pretty surprised about the behavior. I would have expected it to shuffle using the threads/partitions that are already present or use a reasonable system dependent constant like number of cores or the number of cores stated in 'setMaster("local[ . ]")`. The 200 seems like a very arbitrary choice.

Comment: The actual parallelism used is dependent on the architecture you have available. I can guess the motivation for this number: A shuffle causes a complete reorganization of the data so one might as well use that to arrange the data for decent parallelism. But a constant is just a poor choice for that. In case you have few cores and initialization overhead (like in my case) your performance is bad. In case you have many cores (>>200) you actually reduce your parallelism.

Comment: Yeah. that way it is right. not only that, if some one not used or played with that property, it is difficult to identify..